# how to restore default characteristics of terminal in fpc program (+ crt library)?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Default terminal characteristics (on Linux mint) are: black background and grey font. After launching fpc program with TextColor(Red) and TextBackground(White) and quit out of a program, terminal still has red font and white background.

The goal is to find a solution which will restore default characteristics (black background and grey font) of terminal.
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is not pretty nice, but worked (from here: [https://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#TProcess](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#TProcess)).
you should paste the code to the relevant places in a program:

```
uses
    process;
var
    reset_process: TProcess;
begin
    reset_process := TProcess.Create(nil);
    reset_process.Executable := 'reset';
    reset_process.Options := reset_process.Options + [poWaitOnExit];
    reset_process.Execute;
    reset_process.Free
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to set the text background and text color back to black/grey programatically, using `TextColor` and `TextBackground` before `end.`

Comment: you are right, but i would like to find a solution which take into account settings of user`s terminal (TextColor, for example, will be red or black and TextBackground will be blue or green).